# Is my hand/wrist too bent and stretched when handwriting?

Tags: handwriting

I made a snippet of an educational video I've made [here](https://youtube.com/shorts/39V_Aa-q1U8?feature=share). Here is a picture of my hand: -

[image]

I've never recorded my handwriting before. So I've never noticed how stretched and bent and enlongated my wrist is. Is this normal, or should I change it? I've seen some videos on youtube and it doesn't seem like their hands are this bent at all!

I want to change it, because currently, the viewer cannot see what I'm writing before I move my hand away - which is annoying to look at.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to fit within the purpose of this group.  While this group is about helping people with the mechanics of writing, I don't think penmanship is part of the craft of writing or the art of storytelling. Plus, the clip is of someone drawing.  I think a better site would be one focused on either drawing/animation or making better video content for social media and stuff

Comment: @EDL Fair enough. Do you know if there is SE for this kind of stuff?

Comment: no. there are SE for graphicdesign and crafts, both mention drawing.  Since you seem focused on video presentation -- blocking the view as you write/draw -- you are kind of looking for youtube/ticktok performance skills

Comment: If you're worried about obscuring your writing with your hand, one option you could consider is to video it from behind. You'll need thin paper and a transparent hard surface (e.g. glass) to work on, but it works. For example, that's what the artist of ["Tales Of Mere Existence"](https://www.youtube.com/c/AgentXPQ/videos) does.

Answer (score 1):

Two things stand out. Firstly, you are using a type of pen that demands you hold it almost perpendicular to the paper. This influences your grip. Use a good, ordinary ballpoint and you don't have this problem. I like the type of pen you are using and so understand why you use it but you could try others.

Secondly, the conventional grip has the thumb and finger directly onto the pen and not touching each other. This changes the angle of the hand.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Am I using the right grip for this type of pen? If not, does the proper grip have a name? Does my pen type have a name?

Comment: I don't know the name of the grip, just that it was taught in primary schools for many years. Other than roller ball, I don't know a name for the type of pen.

Answer (score 0):

Having graded what feels like a million pages of homework, I have seen a connection between writing content and writing style. I can tell if the writing is writing in a hurry when the penmanship is sloppy and their thoughts are undercooked. I've also seen some absolutely atrocious handwriting which I swear was written with a left foot wearing a mitten. You're handwriting is fine.

As we've all transitioned online, I've also become self-conscious about how my educational content looks on camera. Speaking only for myself, I decided that as long as it's readable, you're fine. The extra effort required to make it beautiful "Disney quality" will likely require more time than you're willing to invest.

(I did pre-print some of my content with some funny fonts for some limited purpose, so as to save time in having my students watch me write it out. They are empowered to slow down the video or even pause it if I'm going too fast.)

There's my $0.02. :)